# Combining Qt with OpenGL: does not compile

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, cmake

I'm trying to create a project in Qt with an `QOpenGLWidget` and CMake as a building tool. The problem is that it does not compile and I don't know why.

```
[...]\include\ui_MainWindow.h:79: błąd: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN13QOpenGLWidgetC1EP7QWidget6QFlagsIN2Qt10WindowTypeEE'
```

That's my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(QtTest VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS OpenGL REQUIRED)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        src/main.cpp
        src/MainWindow.cpp
        src/MainWindow.hpp
        src/MainWindow.ui
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(QtTest
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
else()
    add_executable(QtTest
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
endif()

target_link_libraries(QtTest PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::OpenGL)

set_target_properties(QtTest PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(QtTest)
endif()
```

In my `MainWindow.ui` file I only create an `QOpenGLWidget` widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Qt6 `QOpenGLWidget` was moved to a new module named `OpenGLWidgets`.
To make your program work you need to add `OpenGLWidgets` to your `find_package` command and `Qt6::OpenGLWidgets` to your `target_link_libraries` command.

```
find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Widgets OpenGL OpenGLWidgets REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(QtTest PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets Qt6::OpenGL Qt6::OpenGLWidgets)
```

Comment: I wish there was an easier chance to configure macOS to get along with Qt6 better...

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn What do you mean by this? Most complexity in the given example comes from supporting Qt5 and Qt6. If you decide to skip support for Qt5 it's only a few lines. And the installation of Qt6 can be easily done with homebrew.

Comment: thanks for the blindingly fast answer! I now notice that I was tired when I typed that line... anyway, my point is that I've been sort of dragging and kicking an ancient app designed when Qt **3** was *the* novelty, and which has legacy bits here and there — I just wish to jump straight into Qt6 and get over with it (aye, I couldn't care less about Qt5 support). Homebrew was useful, but I had to do some 30+ symlinks manually (why? I haven't the slightest idea). And now I still have to coerce the many `.pro` and CMakeLists to get everything to link properly...

Comment: Actually, I _did_ manage to coerce everything into compile & link successfully after merely two weeks of refactoring code — not bad, considering that two weeks ago, I didn't even know that 'Qt' is pronounced 'cutie' :) Now I just need to figure out why I have a badly instantiated PlatformIntegration, and I guess that my work will be done :)

Comment: I can feel the pain going directly from Qt3 to Qt6. Been using a toolkit that supports Qt from version 3 to 6. If you look into the code it's a mess with #ifdef . TBH, I don't know why you need to define all those symlinks when installing Qt6 with homebrew. IIRC, there was an option to homebrew to force the creation of the symlinks, but my last work with Qt6 on macOS was one year ago so my brain may fool me.